# Sort stack using two stacks

Tags: java, sorting, stack

My program is supposed to sort a stack such that the smallest item are on the top. I can use a temporary stack, but you may not copy the elements into any other data structure. The program works overall, but I was wondering if there is anything that I can do to make it more efficient/better.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class SortStack {

    Stack sorted;

    public Stack sort(Stack unsorted) {


        int temp2 = 0; // to keep track of number of top of the sorted stack

        while(!unsorted.isEmpty()) {
            int temp1 = (int) unsorted.pop();

            if(sorted == null) { // if sorted stack is empty, create it and push the first number onto it
                sorted = new Stack();
                sorted.push(temp1);
                System.out.println(temp1 + " pushed from s1 to s2");
            } else if(temp1 >= temp2) { // push onto sorted stack if what is popped from original stack >= unsorted stack 
                sorted.push(temp1);
                temp2 = temp1;
                System.out.println(temp1 + " pushed from s1 to s2");
            } else { // keep on popping from sorted stack to unsorted stack until unsortedTop < sortedTop
                    // this will make sure whatever is popped from original stack will not be less than the peek of the sorted stack
                while(temp1 < temp2) {
                    int sortedPop = (int) sorted.pop();
                    unsorted.push(sortedPop);
                    System.out.println(sortedPop + " pushed from s2 to s1");
                    temp2 = (int) sorted.peek();
                }
                sorted.push(temp1); // after both stacks are balanced, push element to sorted stack 
                System.out.println(temp1 + " pushed from s1 to s2");
            }
        }
        return sorted;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SortStack ss = new SortStack();

        Stack unsorted = new Stack();
        unsorted.push(7);
        unsorted.push(10);
        unsorted.push(5);
        unsorted.push(12);
        unsorted.push(8);
        unsorted.push(3);
        unsorted.push(1);

        ss.sort(unsorted);

    }

}
```

Comment: This can be done using just one temp variable. Look at sortstacka() in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253057/sorting-an-unsorted-array-using-3-stacks-in-java). Although the title of the section is sort using 3 stacks, sortstacka() uses just two stacks, the original stack C, and a temp stack B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Generic type declaration

Your `Stack`s are missing the type parameter, i.e. in your case `Stack<Integer>`. This ensures they can only contain `Integer` objects.

#### `static` vs instance fields

`sorted` is the only instance field used in the only method of your `SortStack` class. This means it is likely better to exist as a method variable, and in turn your `SortStack` class becomes an utility class where `sort(Stack<Integer> input)` is now a `static` utility method.

#### Primitive unboxing

On a related note to the first point, you are implicitly relying on primitive unboxing, i.e. converting an `Integer` to `int` when you do this:

```
int temp1 = (int) unsorted.pop();
```

If a `null` is lurking in your `unsorted` object, this will fail.

#### Debugging and variable naming

If possible, use a logging framework like [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) so that you can configure when you want to see the debug statements, instead of simply printing via `System.out.println()`. Also:

```
" pushed from s1 to s2"
```

Isn't that meaningful - is `s1` or `s2` the sorted one? You may want to specify that. Same goes for `temp1` and `temp2`, it's not possible to identify which contains the previous/current iterative element from the `unsorted` or `sorted` stack.

#### Future considerations

If you don't want to restrict to sorting `Stack<Integer>` objects, you can generic-fy it as such:

```
public static <T> sort(Stack<T> input) {
    // ...
}
```

However, you can't use your arithmetic-based comparison, so you can change that to:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> sort(Stack<T> input) {
    // ...
    if (fromUnsorted.compareTo(fromSorted) >= 0) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

And if you will like to make it even more 'generic' and cater for non-`Comparable` types, you can specify a `Comparator<T>` to do so:

```
public static <T> sort(Stack<T> input, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    // ...
    if (comparator.compare(fromUnsorted, fromSorted) >= 0) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```